# Perl multiline regex

Tags: regex, perl, multiline, regex-group

I have a file full of json objects to parse, similar to this one:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("523a58c1e4b09611f4c58a66"),
"_items" : [
    {
        "adGroupId" : NumberLong(1230610621),
        "keywordId" : NumberLong("5458816773")
    },
    {
        "adGroupId" : NumberLong(1230613681),
        "keywordId" : NumberLong("3204196588")
    },
    {
        "adGroupId" : NumberLong(1230613681),
        "keywordId" : NumberLong("4340421772")
    },
    {
        "adGroupId" : NumberLong(1230615571),
        "keywordId" : NumberLong("10525630645")
    },
    {
        "adGroupId" : NumberLong(1230617641),
        "keywordId" : NumberLong("4178290208")
    }
]}
```

I want to take the numbers from inside de NumberLong(). At first I needed just the keywordId, and managed to accomplish it with:

```
cat listado.txt |& perl -ne 'print "$1," if /\"keywordId\" : NumberLong\(\"?(\d*)\"?\)/' keywordIds.txt
```

This generated a comma separated file with the numbers. I now need also de adGroupIds, so I'm trying the following matching regex with no luck:

```
cat ./work/listado.txt |& perl -ne 'print "$1-$2," if /\"adGroupId\" : NumberLong\(\"?(\d*)\"?\),\s*\"keywordId\" : NumberLong\(\"?(\d*)\"?\)/m'
```

The regex matches, but I believe perl is not doing multiline, even though I'm using `/m`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have purpose of doing it with regexes and not with proper tools like [JSON](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON)?

Comment: Well, the file is 100MB and this is just one step of a bigger script which involves python, sed, sort and bash. I would like to solve it this way, but if it's too complicated I'll add it to the python piece I believe...

Comment: The problem is that `perl -n` only reads one line at a time. Using a multiline regexp doesn't help if you're only matching against one line.

Comment: So, how do I match it multiline?

Comment: To match a string containing mutliple lines, you must first have a string containing multiple lines. I mentioned how in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

`/m` affects what `^` and `$` match. You use neither, so `/m` has no effect.

You only read a single line at a time, so you only match against a single line at a time. `/m` cannot possibly cause the regex to match against data that is awaiting to be read from some file handle it doesn't know anything about.

You could load the entire file into memory by using `-0777` and loop over all matches instead of just grabbing the first.

Comment: That returns ok the first group, output: "1230610621-5458816773,". How do I make it keep going?. Oh, and the file is 100MB, if I can avoid uploading it all to mem, better

Comment: `print "$1-$2," while /.../g;`. Or without the extra comma, `push @matches, "$1-$2" while /.../g; END { print join ',' @matches }`

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward with just `grep` and `sed`:

```
grep adGroupId listado.txt | sed -E  "s/[^0-9]+//g"
```

1. Match lines with *adGroupId* in them
2. Remove everything that isn't a digit

Comment: He claims to want the numbers. How is this any different? (Other than the lack of commas)

Comment: You are only capturing the adgroupid numbers, I need both, adgroupid and keywordid, in a file like this: group1-keyword1, group2-keywd2, ...

Comment: There's a big difference between 1-2,3-4,5-6 and 1\n3\n5

Comment: @Nicolas It surprises me that nobody posted a variant in sed yet. `sed -nr 's/.*adGroupId.*\(([0-9]+)\).*/\1/; Te; N; s/\n.*keywordId.*\("([0-9]+)"\).*$/-\1/; H; :e ${g;s/^\n//;s/\n/,/g;p};' <file`

Answer (score 1):

Depending of exact structure of your data you may make use of line numbers:

```
while (<>) {
  if ( /NumberLong\("?(?<nr>\d+)/ ) {
    $.%2 ? print "$+{nr}-" : print "$+{nr}\n";
  }
}
```

Or use flags:

```
my $flag = 0;

while (<>) {
  if ( /NumberLong\("?(?<nr>\d+)/ ) {
    !$flag 
      ? (print "$+{nr}-" and $flag++)
      : (print "$+{nr}\n" and $flag--);
  }
}
```

Or with slurping:

```
use 5.010;
my $file;

{
  local $/;
  $file = <>;
}

while ($file =~ /adGroupId" : NumberLong\("?(?<first>\d+).+?keywordId" : NumberLong\("?(?<second>\d+)/gs ) {
  say "$+{first}-$+{second}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne "print $1.'-' if /adGroupId.+?(\d+)/;print $1.',' if /keywordId.+?(\d+)/" listado.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [File::MultilineGrep](http://search.cpan.org/~rivilism/File-MultilineGrep-0.01/lib/File/MultilineGrep.pm)

Excerpt from its description:
To be considered text files having repeated structures. These structures possess repeated start delimiter, optional stop delimiter and variable contents. That is some or all fields of these structures are optional. A task is to select all whole structures, that contain a specified pattern. This can be done using a multiline regular expressions. But there is a performance issue: Processing time using regular expression is not directly proportional to amount of structures, so that increasing of this amount might cause the reqular expression will never finish. Processing time of the proposed function is directly proportional to amount of structures.